# bind mousewheel and keydown in jquery

Tags: jquery, events, keypress, keydown, mousewheel

I got these code, which should react on mousewheel and keydown:

```
$('#wellcome-box').bind('mousewheel, keydown', function(event){
    console.log(event);
    if(event.which.keyCode == 40){
        alert();
    }
    else
    {
        movesTo('#slide-box-art');
        $('#onto-panel').slideDown(250);
    }
});
```

but all I got is a mousewheel event, but not any keydown. What I do wrong?

Comment: Try `.on('mousewheel keydown', function(event){`, and post your html also

Comment: Its not `.which.keyCode`. Choose one or another

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#wellcome-box').on('mousewheel keydown', function(event){
```

You don't need the comma and `on` is the preferred method call.